# The subscriber to an email list does not receive a return email

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I created a page and have a subscriber field, to collect only the email.
However, the user does not receive a return email with the welcome and I do not receive an email with the registered email.

That is, nothing happens.

I'm using the script below.

**HTML:**

```
 <form action="forms/mail2.php" method="post" role="form" class="">
    <div class="subscribe-form">
            <input type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Seu melhor email"><input type="submit"     value="Inscrever">
    </div>
         
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$to = "contact@server.com.br";
$from = "contact@server.com.br";

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: " . $from;
$headers[] = "Reply-To: " . $from;


$subject = "Nova inscrição na lista";
$body = "Novo usuário inscrito: " . $_POST['email'];

if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers))) {
        echo 'Parabéns seu Email:  (' . $_POST['email'] . ') foi inscrito com sucesso em nossa lista!';
        header('Location: http://url.com.br/');
    } else {
        echo 'Houve um problwma com seu email: (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Houve um problema com seu email:  (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';
}
```

With this script I get the email from the person who signed up, but the person doesn't get any feedback and I don't know how to include this feedback in the script.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$recipient = "contact@server.com.br";
$subject = "Contato do site";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $mailheader, $subject) or die("Error!");
echo "Aguarde o lançamento!";
header('Location: http://server.com.br/');
```

Comment: Check for server errors. If you don't know where those are logged you'll need to find out.

Comment: I checked the logs, no mistake!

Comment: Are you sure you're authorized to send email for that domain? Are you sending literally from `server.com.br`? You must own and control the domain you're sending on behalf of.

Comment: No, I put this url there, just to exemplify, but I have another website in this same hosting and sending email works normally, the problem is that the other application does not capture email, it just sends them.

Comment: @tadman I updated the question, exposing another script that I use and that works partially, it fires an email to myself.

Comment: You need to ensure your PHP SMTP mail configuration is correct. The `mail` function is pretty trashy, I think it just leans on `/usr/bin/sendmail` by default, so unless that's functional it may not do anything useful. There's a multitude of PHP SMTP libraries worth checking out on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org).

Comment: Are you actually using the program `sendmail` as you show in your tags?

Comment: @Rob Yes, I am, I even confirmed here at my hosting, Hostinger.

I don't mind having to change the way I send the email, I just wanted a solution, for this script or another that works well, I researched a lot and found nothing useful.

Comment: I only ask because I've noticed a lot of people using that tag for "sending mail" but aren't using sendmail.